# How to start VLC from NodeJS script (with parameters) using "child_process"?

Tags: node.js, shell, raspberry-pi, vlc, raspberry-pi4

I used to do this with `omxplayer` before, on Raspberry Pi, and it worked fine:

```
const ChildProcess = require("child_process");

ChildProcess.exec(command, function (err) {
    if (err !== null) {
        console.log("" + err);
    } 
});
```

I could pass any omxplayer-related arguments within the command string, without issues.

With VLC on the other hand, executing `cvlc [pathToAudioFile]` doesn't do anything.
Oh, and I tried the exact same command, i.e. using the same file path, from the CLI and it played the audio file perfectly.

So how do I start VLC (using `cvlc`) from within NodeJS and pass arguments to it as well?

Comment: logs? Also possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272921/nodejs-and-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the `cvlc [pathToFile]` command didn't produce an outcome was incorrect permissions on the media file. `chmod`-ing that file with 777 solved the problem.